# `CondaError: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii'` problem on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, conda

I'm trying to update conda on my ubuntu 16 machine for a program, but every time i do I get the following error:

> CondaError: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii',
>   '/info/test/tests/data/\xed\x94\x84\xeb\xa1\x9c\xea\xb7\xb8\xeb\x9e\xa8.README',
>   22, 23, 'ordinal not in range(128)')

I've tried updating conda-build too as that was flagged up as an old version, but that doesn't update either and end up with the same error immediately after telling the update to proceed in the command line. If anyone has any ideas on what I should do I would be very grateful, as I am stumped and cant find anything to help solve the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/FeatureLabs/featuretools/issues/246

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by doing the following:

`conda remove conda-build`
`conda install conda-build`
`conda update conda`

"conda update conda" was repeated until I got:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```